# Microsoft Outlook: Search for original sender in forwarded emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, conditional-statements

I have to search the Outlook email inbox (PST file) of an employee based on certain criteria.

Basically, I want evaluate data requests from external senders (as identified by their email addresses), but not from the employees colleagues. However, sometimes colleagues forward these data requests to the employee. Consequently, I would need to identify the original sender in my search query.

The query could look like this:

```
subject: "certain data" OR body: "certain data" AND NOT original_from: "list of email addresses"
```

I'm happy to export the pst-file to any other freeware for further analysis.

Answer (score 0):

We can use **Query Builder** in Outlook advanced search to reach your requirement.

As we know, after the emails is forwarded, the sender will be displayed as "From: XXX" in the body of the email.
[image]

Considering that you need to exclude the email from user A be forwarded, we need to add a condition "Messages don't contain "From: XXX". So the search criteria is as shown in the below image:
[image]

If you don't see Query Builder in Outlook advanced search, please refer to this thread:
[How do I Enable Query Builder in Outlook 365 Version 1810 Build 11001.20074 Click-to-run?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/how-do-i-enable-query-builder-in-outlook-365/ff503ea6-8fa1-4718-bfc6-0c6db9fd35eb)